# Store date inside .accdb file

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, date

I am using vb.net to store value into .accdb file. In my form I have a box with date and it shows current date. Tried to print it out in a MsgBox and it shows the date correctly but when I store it inside .accdb file it says that the date is 1905-05-31 WTF??? I have no idea where it is coming from.

```
DateTimePickerIFT.Text (it is actually DateTimePicker IFT at the end is how I name it)
```

This is how I get my date from DateTimePicker box. I have noticed if I move the date one day back the value stored is 1905-06-01 which is (2012-10-23 in a datepickerbox) and when I get 1905-05-31 selected date is (2012-10-24). I am not initializing date anywhere just getting it from the box and sending it directly to .accdb file.

I tried making .accdb filed value as [date/time] or [text] with same results.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried getting the value using DateTimePickerIFT.Value instead of .Text. How are you inserting the value into the database?

Comment: Yep, the date qualifier in Access is the **#** sign, most other databases use singles quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently needed to put this outside the string value #" & DateTimePickerIFT.Value.ToShortDateString & "#